# Help with Nilpotent Transformation Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, nilpotence

I have the following linear algebra textbook question and I'm not really sure where to begin with it:

Let $V$ be a (possibly infinite-dimensional) vector space. We say a linear map $T: V \rightarrow V$ is nilpotent if there is a positive integer $k$ such that $T^k = 0$. If $T$ is a nilpotent map, then there is a unique positive integer $k$ such that $T^{k} = 0$ and $T^{k−1} \neq 0$.

Let $T : V \rightarrow V$ be a nilponent linear map. Suppose the
nilpotency index of T is $k$. Show that if $0 ≤ i < k$, then

1. $\operatorname{Im}(T^{i+1}) \subsetneq \operatorname{Im}(T)$, and
2. $\ker T^i \subsetneq T^{i+1}$.

(The notation $X \subsetneq Y$ means $X ⊂ Y$ and $X \neq Y$ , i.e. that $X$ is a proper subset of $Y$).

**Hint:** It should be easy to
see that $\operatorname{Im}(T^{i+1}) \subset \operatorname{Im}(T)$ and $\ker(T^i) \subset \ker(T^{i+1})$. To prove the properness of the inclusions, first argue that
$T(\operatorname{Im}(T^i)) = \operatorname{Im}(T^{i+1})$ and $\operatorname{Im}(T^i) \subset \ker(T^{k-i})$.

**My thought process so far is the following:** since T is nilpotent, then for some integer $k$, $T^k = 0$. Up until that point, we know that $T^i \neq 0$. Supposing then that $i=k-1$, then $T^{i+1}=T^k=0$, which means all vectors under the linear transformation $T^k$ would go to zero. Hence, $ker(T^k)$ consists of all possible input vectors. Accordingly $Im(T^k)$ would have dimension 0, implying that $Im(T^k) \subsetneq  Im(T^{k-1})$. I'm not sure if this is the right direction or how I can then generalize it for any value of $i$

Comment: Note that users are expected to provide context for their problems, [as is explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it is helpful that you told us that this is a linear algebra textbook question, but it would be helpful if you could tell us what your thoughts on the problem are and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these sorts of questions it's best to argue by contradiction. We have that
$T^i = T^{i-1}T$ and so $Im(T^i) \subseteq Im(T^{i-1})$. Suppose we had
$$
Im(T^i) = T^i(V) = T^{i+1}(V) = Im(T^{i-1}) \neq \{0\}
$$
Then
$$
T^{i+2}(V) = T(T^{i+1}(V)) = T(T^{i}(V)) = T^{i+1}(V) \neq 0
$$
and so by induction, $T^{i + n}(V) \neq 0$ for all $n$. This is a contradiction. In particular we have that $T^{i}(V)$ is properly contained in $T(V)$ for $i > 1$. For the kernels you can apply the hint, if $T^i(v) = 0$ then $T^{i+1}(v) = 0$ and so
$$
\ker T^{i} \subseteq \ker T^{i+1}
$$
If ker $T^i = \ker T^{i+1}$ then we'd have that $Im(T^{k-(i+1)}) \subseteq \ker T^{i+1} = \ker T^{i}$ and hence $T^i(T^{k-(i+1)}(V)) = T^{k-1}(V) = 0$. This is a contradiction on the nilpotency of $T$.